# member access within misaligned address when accesing trie Node

Tags: c++

```
struct trieNode{
    vector<trieNode*> children;
    bool isEndOfWord;
    trieNode() : children(26, NULL){
        isEndOfWord = false;
    }
};

class WordDictionary {
public:
    trieNode *myTrie;
    WordDictionary() {
        trieNode *myTrie = new trieNode();
        cout<< (myTrie->children[17] == NULL? "abc":"def");      <== working here
    }
    
    void addWord(string word) {
        cout<< (myTrie->children[0] == NULL? "abc":"def");       <==failing here
    }
};
```

Error:

```
member access within misaligned address
```

I am getting no idea, why the same variable would work in the constructor, but give memory issue in another function.

Comment: `trieNode *myTrie = new trieNode();` defined a new local variable named `myTrie` that is district from the member variable `myTrie`. the local variable is live and set up in the constructor, then goes out of scope and is lost. The member `myTrie` is never initialized at all. Use `myTrie = new trieNode();` in the constructor to set the member variable.

Comment: Thanks.. that was stupid

Comment: Also a good place to use the Member Initializer List: `WordDictionary(): myTrie(new trieNode()) {cout<< (myTrie->children[17] == NULL? "abc":"def");}`. The compiler might be able to perform some slick optimizations, but for a pointer assignment, probably no improvement. Makes it impossible to get out of the constructor alive without a valid `myTrie`, though, so conceptually worth it.

Comment: @cosmos You should set the pointer to NULL instead of allocating dynamically memory myTrie = nullptr; Or in the mem-initializer list of the constructor myTrie( nullptr )